# How to determine a $n\times n$ matrix $H$ has non trivial kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra

We know $\vec{u}$ is a non-zero vector, and the equation of $H$ is:

$$I-\frac{\mathbb{uu}^T}{||\mathbb{u}||^2_2}$$

Is there any *slick&quick* method besides defining $\vec{u}$ to be $(u_1,u_2,...,u_n)^T$ then extend the whole matrix to solve the question?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Note $u$ is in the kernal...

Comment: If $v$ is in the kernel of $I-A$ ($A$ being any matrix) then from $(I-A)v = 0$ one can deduce $v = Av$. This tells you not only that $v$ is is in the range of $A$, but that $v$ is fixed by $A$. With $A$ as here we're suddenly focusing on what vectors are in the range of  $uu^T/\|u\|_2^2$, which gets you to thinking about $u$ pretty quickly. It's not as much of a rabbit out of a hat as it looks.

Comment: @saulspatz got it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(I-uu^T/(u^Tu))v = 0$ if and only if $v = u(u^Tv)/(u^Tu)$, so the kernel is precisely the span of $u$.

Comment: Understand it now, thank you so much!